# Binary I/O in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, binary

I am experimenting with binary reading and writing to and from files in Python. I am trying to teach myself a bit of programming (it's not really teaching myself, since I use the internet, but anyway...). My problem is that reading a file in Python in binary does not actually output the bits to me, but seems to process it into text already.

Example:

My system has a file "Test.txt" in the same folder as the script.

The content of this file is the following text written in notepad:

```
Testing Temp "Testing"
```

This is a small piece of the code that is giving me some confusion:

```
f=open("Test.txt", "rb")
print(f.read(22))
```

This results in the following output:

```
b'Testing Temp "Testing"'
```

However, I want bits in the form of a string (so a string of 0's and 1's) as output. How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean "bits"? what's the output you expect?

Comment: You are right, I wasn't very clear. I'm looking for a string of 0's and 1's. I have edited my post.

Comment: what are you expecting to learn with this excersize?

Comment: I am trying to write a script that can encrypt and decrypt files using elliptic curve cryptography (MV ElGamal). However, I'd like to be able to encrypt all kinds of files, not just text files. I have already written the encryption and decryption functions, however I wrote them in a way that requires a string of 0's and 1's as input.

Comment: thats really not what you should be doing imho ... you should handle it properly and treat it as a byte... not a string ... this excersize seems like it will just confuse you more than enlighten you

Comment: I did it like this because my encryption function requires exactly 46 bytes as input to be divided into two blocks of 23. I then convert both blocks into integers for the encryption algorithm. However, I'm not sure how to do this with bytes (especially the converting from a block of bytes into an integer). This seemed like the easiest way to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a sequence of *bytes* (note the `b` at the beginning).
You can access the value of every single byte using indexing. In your example, if `s=f.read(22)` then `s[0]` will be `84` which is the ASCII code for `T`.

If you want to obtain the binary representation of a byte you use the `bin` built-in:

```
>>> bin(84)
'0b1010100'
```

It also adds the `0b` prefix which is python's prefix for binary literals:

```
>>> 0b1010100
84
```

To obtain the bit-per-bit binary representation you can simply access every byte and call `bin` on each value:

```
def to_bits(contents):
    return ''.join(bin(byte)[2:].zfill(8) for byte in contents)
```

which results in:

```
>>> to_bits(b'Testing Temp "Testing"')
'01010100011001010111001101110100011010010110111001100111001000000101010001100101011011010111000000100000001000100101010001100101011100110111010001101001011011100110011100100010'
```

Note that you have to call `zfill(8)` because `bin` can return representation shorter than 8 bits:

```
>>> bin(1)[2:]
'1'
>>> bin(1)[2:].zfill(8)
'00000001'
```

Comment: Is this the easiest way? It seems like a bit of an overly complicated method. Is there no built-in function?

Comment: wouldnt you need to call `ord(byte)` as well (at least in 2.6)? ...  @Dasherman its one line ... its not really that complicated

Comment: I tried it. ord(byte) isn't needed, since f.read(22)[0] results in 84, not "T".

Comment: @JoranBeasley No, it's not needed in python3+ (the question is tagged as such).

Comment: @Dasherman No there is no built-in function for the simple fact that this isn't a really useful thing in usual programs and it's really easy to implement.